# Database design for a sport ranking column containing ranking numbers and DNF (did not finish) or DNS (Did not start)

Tags: mysql, database-design

i'm currently setting up a MySQL database which should contain these sport results:

| sport_rank | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 |
| 2 | name2 |
| ... | ... |
| DNF | nameX |
| DNS | nameY |

my question is pretty simple, how would you optimally design the "sport_rank" column in your table declaration since it contains numbers and strings (DNF, DNS), keeping in mind that you would like to be able to order it correctly afterwards (ascending numbers, DNF and lastly DNS)

many thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to define a column in SQL server that may contain either an integer or a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858323/what-is-the-best-way-to-define-a-column-in-sql-server-that-may-contain-either-an)

Comment: Please before considering posting read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask], [Help] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title.